# Facebook Wall Status

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Let me first thank you for allowing me to ask some question here. I hope you can help me with the following question.

I want to post some message on User's Facebook status. It is successful with the following code:

```
$params = array('access_token'=>$access_token, 'message'=>$message);
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbuserid."/feed";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

What do I need to add or do to post image and/or link affiliate to this post msg? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish a photo to a user's album, you must have the `publish_stream` permission. With that grantedd, you can upload a photo by issuing an `HTTP POST` request with the photo content and an optional description to one these to Graph API connections:

- `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos` - The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded this way will then be added to this same album.
- `https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos` - The photo will be published to a specific, existing photo album, represented by the `ALBUM_ID`.

**Example:**

```
<?php
       $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
       $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
       $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";

       $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

       //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
       if(empty($code)){ 
          $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
           . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
           . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
           .  "&scope=publish_stream";
          echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
          . "'</script>");
         }
        else {
          $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
           . "client_id=" . $app_id 
           . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
           . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
           . "&code=" . $code;
          $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
          $params = null;
          parse_str($response, $params);
          $access_token = $params['access_token'];

         // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
         $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
         . "access_token=" .$access_token;

         echo '<html><body>';
         echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
         .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
         echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
         echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
         echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
         echo '<input name="message" 
             type="text" value=""><br/><br/>';
         echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
         echo '</form>';
         echo '</body></html>';
      }
?>
```

**Sample Output:**

```
{
   "id": "1001207389476"
}
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you help me by explaining? I do have the access token and image link already.. How do I post to user timeline?